# Grails 3.0.1 spring security core return Gradle build terminated with error: Compilation failed

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

i have integrated spring security core 3.0.4 to grails 3.0.1. After running s2-quickstart grails to create my user, role and requestMap domains, my application will return the error **Gradle build terminated with error: Compilation failed**
In the file user.groovy, the line **import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService** is underlined in red.
Also in the role.groovy file the line **@GrailsCompileStatic** is also underlined.
please help me. thank you.

User content

```
packages securites
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import groovy.transform.ToString
import grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic

@GrailsCompileStatic
@EqualsAndHashCode(includes='username')
@ToString(includes='username', includeNames=true, includePackage=false)
class Utilisteur implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    SpringSecurityService springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    Set<Roles> getAuthorities() {
        (UtilisteurRoles.findAllByUtilisteur(this) as List<UtilisteurRoles>)*.roles as Set<Roles>
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService?.passwordEncoder ? springSecurityService.encodePassword(password) : password
    }

    static transients = ['springSecurityService']

    static constraints = {
        password blank: false, password: true
        username blank: false, unique: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }
}
```

Role content

```
package securites

import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import groovy.transform.ToString
import grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic

@GrailsCompileStatic
@EqualsAndHashCode(includes='authority')
@ToString(includes='authority', includeNames=true, includePackage=false)
class Roles implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    String authority

    static constraints = {
        authority blank: false, unique: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        cache true
    }
}
```

Comment: You mentioned underlined in red so I assume you are talking about an editor in an IDE.  Which IDE are you using and separate question, does the code compile successfully from the command like `./gradlew cG`?

Comment: mention the stacktrace also

Comment: I use NetBeans as IDE, when I compile I have an error
 Gradle build terminated with error: Compilation failed

Answer (score 0):

Update your spring security core plugin to 3.1